# Unable to echo data in mysql

Tags: php

I want to get the data in the mysql database and output them in each case as in the database. But when I display them, just see the word `"Vi tri cua nguoi dung: Array"` without seeing the data. i test by use JSON, I get the result on the screen is:

```
"[{" Kinhdo ":" 106.71246126888674 "," Vido ":" 10.78865449101134 "}]"
```

Can you help me?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxx");
mysql_select_db("a4602996_lv"); 
$query_insert="select Kinhdo,Vido from VietMap where id = (select max(id) from VietMap)";
$sql = mysql_query($query_insert);
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $json[] = $row;
    }
}
//print(json_encode($json).'<br/>');
print 'Vi tri cua nguoi dung: '.$json['Kinhdo'];
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
{
  echo "<pre />";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
    print_r($row);
    $json[] = $row;
  }
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

and you shold provide offset to $json array like :

```
$json[0]['Kinhdo'];    //for 1st record
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please look into the following solutions hope this will help you

```
// If you are Expecting only one row from the Query Use the following code block

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $json = $row; 
  }
}
//print(json_encode($json).'<br/>');
print 'Vi tri cua nguoi dung: '.$json['Kinhdo'];


/**************************************************************/

// If you are Expecting More than one row from the Query Use the following code block

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $json = $row; 
  }
}
//print(json_encode($json).'<br/>');
foreach($json as $j){
  print 'Vi tri cua nguoi dung: '.$j['Kinhdo'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump() or print_r() or loop through the array

Answer (score 0):

That means that your data returned is an array. use **print_r** instead

Comment: i use print_r ('Vi tri cua nguoi dung: '.$json[0]); and recieve "Vi tri cua nguoi dung: Array"

Comment: simply print_r($json); That will give you the array

Answer (score 0):

You var `$json` is a multi-dimensional array.

```
$json[] = $row; // assining array to an array index make a array in array
```

you need to  loop threw `$json`